# Sort a list of Numbers as letters

Tags: code-golf, number

So, you have a random list (random meaning it doesn't matter what order it is in) of numbers with a length of `n`, where n is a positive integer smaller than 1000 and larger than 1.

The random list must contain every number from `0 to (n - 1)`. Eg: [0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4] (where n is 6).

**Note: If there is more than one digit you do not translate like English - 11 is not "eleven", it is "one one".**

Your task is to sort these numbers, but there are some difference to normal sorting:

1. You **have** to sort them as if they were the numbers expressed as words, in alphabetical order, but you cannot replace the numbers with letters [1]
2. At any given time, the list must contain exactly the same numbers in the exact quantities as the original list, you cannot add or remove any

**Test Cases**

```
n = 6
[0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4] = [5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 0] (sorted like this but not this - ["five", "four", "one", "three", "two", "zero"])
n = 8
[0, 3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 6, 4] = [5, 4, 1, 7, 6, 3, 2, 0] (sorted like this but not this - ["five", "four", "one", "seven", "six", "three", "two", "zero"])
```

This is `code-golf`, so the smallest answer in **bytes** wins.

[1]: You may create another list to do the sorting, but the original list must have the same contents at all times

Comment: You need to define *exactly* how numbers translate to words. For example: is `101` one hundred and one, one hundred one, one zero one ... or ... what?

Comment: Can we internally convert numbers to words, sort, then convert them back?

Comment: Both (1) and (2) are unobservable.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart, as Jonathan mentioned, that's an unobservable requirement.

Comment: Also, I don't really see the point of the input apart from the length. It doesn't matter what permutation the input is, if it is always the range from 1 to `n`, since the output is going to be sorted anyway

Comment: So are we expected to take a list as a reference?  What if our language uses only immutable data?

Comment: If this would be made clearer to be re-opened, it probably will be closed again [as a dupe of this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172891/pronunciationsort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 21 bytes

```
#~SortBy~IntegerName&
```

there is also a message that shouldn't be there

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X7kuOL@oxKmyzjOvJDU9tcgvMTdV7X9AUWZeiUNadFBiXkp@bnBibkFOKoiTnhptoKNgGhsby4VfiTlhJYYGQDX/AQ)

Comment: While I do not agree with the unobservable requirement it is nonetheless there... "you cannot replace the numbers with letters" - pretty sure that is what `IntegerName` will do.

Comment: I didn't replace them.. it was the internal criterion. I guess the OP should decide